# Initialization of array-of-classes member of a class

Tags: c++

I want to initialize array-of-classes member of a class

```
const int count = 5;

class In
{
   float rate;
public:
   In( int index )
   {
      rate = index / count;
   }
};

class Out
{
   In ins[count];

public:
   Out() : /* ??? */
   {
   }
};
```

Can I obtain index of instance of In in initialization ins if I will rely on initialization list of `Out::Out()`

Comment: Can you explain your requirement more clearly?

Comment: @Raza I think he wants to initialize the array in the initializer list.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that. You need to define a default constructor for `In`.

Or better yet, use a `std::vector`.

EDIT: Might be supported in C++11, not sure though.